# Show a different text for the selected option for `<select>`s

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the text that's displayed in the `<select>` to be different from the selected `<option>`'s text. I have limited width to work with, so if I display all the text in the `<option>`, then some text with be cut off.

For example, if my markup is this:

```
<select>
  <option>Open (some description)</option>
  <option>Closed (a bunch of text</option>
</select>
```

When the first option is selected, I want to show only the word "Open" to save space. I can't just use Javascript to replace the text because if the user opens the select, then they'll see the shortened text.

Is there a way to do this using the `<select>` tag (i.e. without using a custom selector)?

Comment: I don't think you're going to manage this without JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately, IMHO, there is no way without JS =)

Comment: JS is fine, I'm saying that the simple JS solution of replacing the text won't work. I.e. you can replace `Open (some description)` with `Open` if it's selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using JS, you can add a `focus` and `blur` event listeners which modify the text of the `option`s:

```js
function focus() {
  [].forEach.call(this.options, function(o) {
    o.textContent = o.getAttribute('value') + ' (' + o.getAttribute('data-descr') + ')';
  });
}
function blur() {
  [].forEach.call(this.options, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
    o.textContent = o.getAttribute('value');
  });
}
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.shortened-select'), function(s) {
  s.addEventListener('focus', focus);
  s.addEventListener('blur', blur);
  blur.call(s);
});
```

```html
<select class="shortened-select">
  <option value="Open" data-descr="some description"></option>
  <option value="Closed" data-descr="a bunch of text"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the closest solution. I'd also trigger `blur()` when an option is selected.

Comment: @Linksku Then you can add something like `s.addEventListener('change', function(){this.blur()});`

Answer (score 3):

You could create a second `select` element, which has abbreviated options.  Show it by default and hide the `select` element with un-abbreviated options.

When the abbreviated `select` is hovered, show the other `select` element.

When you change an option, set the abbreviated `select` element's `selectedIndex` to match, which will keep both elements in sync:

```js
document.getElementById('s2').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('s1').selectedIndex= this.selectedIndex;
});
```

```css
#s1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#s2 {
  display: none;
}

#s2:hover, #s1:hover + select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<select id="s1">
  <option>Open</option>
  <option>Closed</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option>Open (some description)</option>
  <option>Closed (a bunch of text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not **without JS** as the OP requested

Comment: The OP tagged JavaScript, and simply mentioned that he couldn't use JavaScript to change the text.

Comment: read it this way: **can't just use Javascript .. because if** means **I don't want it for some reasons.**

Comment: The OP can clarify if needed.  Since JavaScript is tagged, it may be an option.

Comment: Javascript is fine, I just didn't want a custom selector that doesn't use `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way w/o javascript and trying to save space is:

```html
<select size="5">
  <option title="(some description)">Open</option>
  <option title="(a bunch of text)">Closed</option>
</select>
```

`title` will appear as tooltipp once the mouse hovers over the option

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ywv0uab/

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS pseudo-elements. Since they are only styles, they don't affect the value of the `select`, so the inserted text won't be shown when the `select` is closed.

```css
option:after {
  content: ' (' attr(data-descr) ')';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option data-descr="some description">Open</option>
  <option data-descr="a bunch of text">Closed</option>
</select>
```

If you want the `select` to shrink to the width of the short text, you can only display the pseudo-element at `:focus`.

```css
select:focus > option:after {
  content: ' (' attr(data-descr) ')';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option data-descr="some description">Open</option>
  <option data-descr="a bunch of text">Closed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My guess is that the problem with this code is that text is added as a sibling of the `option` element (using the `::after` pseudo element). The only text that the browser should render is the value of the `label` attribute, or the element's text content.

Comment: I can't get this to work :(   If this work, it will be the best solution ever! (here is the jsfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/esL39f6g/`)