# Set Option Value as Select text

Tags: html, jquery, select

Need assistance

I need to have a select function where as

```
<select class="form-control">
<option value="4100">4100 : Mass Collections</option>
<option value="4200">4200 : Stole Fees</option>
<select>
```

[image]

now I don't want to include the code description after selecting an option, it should be code only appearing on the select box like this.

[image]

I have tried this Jquery script

```
$('select').change(function() {

   var code= $('option:selected',this).text().split(' : ');
   $('option:contains('+code[0]+')',this).val(code[0]);

})
```

but every time I do this checking in dropdown the option omitted the description entirely. How do I prevent this.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the idea of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180509/show-a-different-text-for-the-selected-option-for-selects): add the description only when the element have focus:

```js
$('select').on("focus", function(s) {
  for (var o of this.options) {
    o.textContent = o.getAttribute('value') + ': ' + o.dataset.descr;
  }
});

$('select').on("blur", function(s) {
  for (var o of this.options) {
    o.textContent = o.getAttribute('value');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
<option value="4100" data-descr="Mass Collections">4100</option>
<option value="4200" data-descr="Stole Fees">4200</option>
<select>
```

Comment: oh wow, Thanks man. This works on my needs.  (Why I haven't stumble on this answer, keep struggling for hours on Google). You're a Google Guru my man. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I could do.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('select').change(function(s) {
    for (var option of this.options) {
      option.label = option.text;
    };
    this.selectedOptions[0].label = this.selectedOptions[0].value;
  });
});
```

Better to check it with more options,

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="4100">4100 : Mass Collections</option>
  <option value="4200">4200 : Stole Fees</option>
  <option value="4300">4300 : Something Else</option> 
<select>
```